# Match everything except a selection of words starting from word1 and ending at word2

Tags: regex

I am trying to match 'match me please' within the following String in Python flavor:

bar\nStartOfString\nignoreMe\ntoBeIgnored\n**match me please**\nignoreYou\nEndOfString\nfoo

The result has to exclude ignoreMe, toBeIgnored and ignoreYou as the position of these words is relative.

What I've tried so far:

```
StartOfString((?!ignoreMe)(?!toBeIgnored)(?!ignoreYou).*)EndOfString

\b(?!ignoreMe|ignoreYou|toBeIgnored)\b\S+
```

https://regex101.com/r/VaROsW/2

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Note that `\n` in your string are most likely line break chars, and if you plan to use any online regex testers, you need to replace `\n`s with real line breaks. Have a look at `StartOfString(?:\n(?:ignoreMe|toBeIgnored|ignoreYou))*\n(.*?)(?:\n(?:ignoreMe|toBeIgnored|ignoreYou))*\nEndOfString` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fkZoHH/1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a capture group to capture what you want.

If you want to match `\n` (backslash and an `n` char), you can match as least amount of characters between the words in the alternation.

```
(?:(?:ignore(?:Me|You)|toBeIgnored)\\n)+(.*?)\\n(?:ignore(?:Me|You)|toBeIgnored)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fxhyE3/1)

If `\n` is a newline, you can prevent matching the words in the alternation using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?:ignore(?:Me|You)|toBeIgnored)((?:\n(?!ignore(?:Me|You)|toBeIgnored).*))\n(?:ignore(?:Me|You)|toBeIgnored)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HBbTVu/1)